# Sumar datos obtenidos por hora sql analizer

Tags: sql

[image: tengo esta consulta y me arroja los resultados que se muestran abajo, quiero ordenarlos por hora]

```
select 
*
FROM [YFAIDB].[dbo].[PKG_PACKING]
  where ID_PACKING 
  in ('REMOTE BEZEL-LH', 'REMOTE BEZEL-RH') 
  And 
  LAST_UPDATE between '2023-08-26 15:00:00.100' and '2023-08-26 16:00:00.377'
```

[image: Busco algo asi]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y cual es el problema?